# Windows 10 errratic possibly infected

Tags: windows, boot, virus

For a week or two I found my system to be rather slow after a fresh boot. I came to thinking it had some sort of infection or virus. Even though Defender had never reported any problem, four days ago I decided to install Comodo Suite which I had used for a few years before Windows 10. A full scan four days ago was performed with any virus reposted. Same with a quick scan today.

Things got worse. Now just a few services are running after a fresh boot.
[Services running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyhnw.png)Among the problems I ran into let me mention a few:

- Windows Event Viewer Service after a long wait only
- No Volume Shadow Copy Service (no access to Restore point)
- Cannot run sfc.exe /scannow
- No Windows Module Installer
- WiFi is always on Flight Mode
- chkdsk.exe on reboot halts at 13% for hours

  My system: HP Probook 450 G2, Windows Pro 10 (Version 1607, Build 14393.447)

What is the cause virus, trojan or alike, motherboard, ..Anybody's help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are going to have to reduce the scope of this question. A non-English screenshot isn't very helpful.  "Cannot run sfc.exe /scannow" - Please provide specifics on the reason SFC cannot be ran.  Provide the output of DISM repair command, tons of documentation on what that command is, edit your question to include all this information.  Include the log file for SFC also, the fact the system halts when you perform a chkdsk, indicates you should simply replace the hdd.  Use the tool of your choice to provide us the current health of your drive.  Update your question to include that information.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your quick answer.I admit I overlooked those 4 lines. They relate to User Data Access, User Data Storage, Contacts(?) Data, and Host Synchronization. As to the scope of the question, I was only trying to describe the context to the issue mentioned at the end: Virus or motherboard or other.

Comment: Edit your question to include the information to determine if your system requires image is corrupt.  What other security software have you used besides Windows Defender.  Malware/Virus security is best when you have software that targets multiple types of infections (i.e One for virus other for malware)

Answer (score 1):

**If it is malware** it is difficult to remove while your existing OS is infected.
Best choices, in order:

1. If you've made backup images: Boot from a rescue CD (e.g. Macrium Reflect) and restore a **complete** disk image you've made from long before the issue. Restore everything, even boot sectors etc. You might lose some recent work, but should be able to return to a known good configuration. This will also fix any OS issues *other* than malware.
2. Otherwise: On another, *clean* machine, create a boot disk with malware removal tools, such as the [Kaspersky RescueDisk](https://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk) or the [Avira Rescue System](http://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system). Comodo also offers a boot disk. Boot from the disk and *try* to remove the malware. This will not help if you have OS issues, though.
3. If you cannot remove the malware, save essential documents to other media (and scan them for malware), *completely* format the disk, and reinstall the OS. This should also resolve intrinsic OS issues.

Comment: I have to skip your choice no. 1, but fortunately I do have backup of my data (sure it has to be scanned). I will jump into choice no.2, or Chris suggestion. If no success, the fresh install will be the solution. I Do appreciate your comment.

Answer (score -2):

Windows Defender will not catch all viruses. It does not have very good ratings compared to the the well known antivirus solutions such as Kapersky.
When the situation gets to this stage, the usual solution we use is to boot from a LINUX disk and run several antivirus programs.
A warning here: CLAM shows more fake positives than others.
The reason why it must be a LINUX boot disk is obvious from the symptoms you are describing. You will find that when you try to run a commercial Windows based antivirus, the virus will block the antivirus program.
Linux operates outside Windows, so it can also find rootkit viruses.
No Windows based antivirus program can find a rootkit virus because the virus installs itself before Windows loads.
Unfortunately I can not tell you which virus you are looking for because several of them give the symptoms you are describing.
It is very unlikely that this is a hardware problem.

Comment: I have not found a single virus infection that Windows Defender can't detect that Kasperky can detect.